# Symfony : How to fetch all object data from entity related with oneToMany relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I have "Car" and "Booking" entities related with oneToMany relationship :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;
    
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CarRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("registrationNumber")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */

class Car
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=9)
     */
    private $registrationNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Booking::class, mappedBy="car")
     */
    private $bookings;

/**
     * @return Collection|Booking[]
     */
    public function getBookings(): Collection
    {
        return $this->bookings;
    }

}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BookingRepository::class)
 */
class Booking
{
    const STATUS = [
        0 => 'Pending',
        1 => 'Canceled',
        2 => 'Confirmed',
        3 => 'Approved',
    ];


    public function  __construct()
    {
        $this->request_date = new \DateTime('now');
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Car::class, inversedBy="bookings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $car;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, options={"default": "Pending"})
     */
    private $status = self::STATUS[0];

    
    public function getCar(): ?Car
    {
        return $this->car;
    }

    public function setCar(?Car $car): self
    {
        $this->car = $car;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function getBookingStatus(): ?string
    {
        return self::STATUS[$this->status];
    }

    public function setStatus(string $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }
 
}
```

---

```
public function book(Request $request, Car $car)
    {
        $booked_car = $car;
        $booking = new Booking();
        $booking->setCar($booked_car);
        $form = $this->createForm(BookingType::class, $booking);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $booking = $form->getData();
            $this->em->persist($booking);
            $this->em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Démande envoyée avec success');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('car.index');
        }
        $this->addFlash('error', 'une erreur dans le système');
        return $this->render('booking/book.html.twig',[
            'booking' => $booking,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

When dump $booking variable in the twig or in the index page which list all bookings, every car object in booking object has only the id field, others are null ! I want to get every field of car object related to booking full of data to show it in the twig view ! in the method book I get the id variable sent with request and put it with setCar method, should I create a query to search byId and affect every attribute one by one !!

[image: dump image]

Comment: if you look closely, you see the class of your car is `Proxies_\Car` which is a lazy-loading wrapper around the ´Car`, when you access any attribute on it, it'll load the object.

Comment: so ? how could I change my code to fill all Car object attribute inside booking object ?

Comment: you can just do $car->getModel() for example

Comment: $car->getModel() return a string params !

Comment: What he means is that if you use a getter that is not getId, the rest of the data will be loaded too, not just the data of the getter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of relation is in lazy loading by default. So since you didn't call any getter of the car object, you only have the id displayed (since it's stored in the booking object too).
But this is only in the context of the dump, as soon as you'll try to use a getter of the car (except getId) it will load the rest.

If you really need the whole car data to be loaded with the booking data, you can use `fetch="EAGER"` in the ManyToOne relation, but you would need a valid reason to do that.